# Is it effective to use one-hot encoding when its dimension is as large as thousands

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, encoding

Here I try to construct a classifier using DNN(deep neural network) with its inputs being many portfolios. In essence, each portfolio contains several stocks which are labeled by there inner-code, for example "1430" or "5560", etc. Since the inner-code is discrete digital number, I prefer to use on-hot encoding to represent each portfolio. However, there are as many as a few thousand different inner-code which means that the dimension of on-hot code may also be that large. I wonder whether the dimension is too large for real training and is there any way to solve or ease this problem, such as using PCA afterward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In neural networks applied to natural language processing normally each possible word (or sub-words) is handled as an individual token, and normally the *vocabulary* (the set of supported tokens) is around 32K. These tokens are typically one-hot encoded. Therefore, **there is not inherent problem in having one-hot encoded vectors with thousands of components**. However, the amount and variety of training data should *support* the dimensionality of the model for it not to overfit. Note that in NLP, these one hot encodings are used as expected outputs of the model, over which to compute maximum likelihood (categorical cross-entropy) together with the output of the model (a softmax).

Depending on how you are using this portfolio information, **another option would be to have an [embedding layer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/182775/40048)**, which *embeds* discrete values into a continuous representation space (whose dimensionality is a hyperparameter of the model). This would be possible if this information is used as *input* to the model. In those cases, you input an integer number, which is used to index the embedded vector table.