# How does the character convolution work in ELMo?

Tags: nlp, convolutional-neural-network, allennlp

When I read the original ELMo paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.05365.pdf), I'm stumped by the following line:

> The context insensitive type representation uses 2048 character n-gram convolutional filters
> followed by two highway layers (Srivastava et al., 2015) and a linear projection down to a 512 representation.

The Srivastava citation only seems to relate to the highway layer concept. So, what happens prior to the biLSTM layer(s) in ELMo? As I understand it, one-hot encoded vectors (so, 'raw text') are passed to a convolutional filter and a linear projection? How should I think of input and output dimensions? I get the feeling that perhaps there used to be a detailed explanation somewhere on allennlp.org (or perhaps their github repo), but it has perhaps been deemed outdated or unnecessary since?

I hope the question makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to understand how ELMo's character convolutions work is by directly inspecting [the source code](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/main/allennlp/modules/elmo.py).

There, in the [`forward` method](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/main/allennlp/modules/elmo.py#L359), you can see that the input to the network is a tensor of dimensions `(batch_size, sequence_length, 50)`, where 50 is the maximum number of characters per word. Therefore, before passing the text to the network, it is segmented in words, and each character is encoded as an integer value.

This is what happens in the `forward` method before the highway layers:

- The tensor gets prepended and appended sentence boundary tokens (beginning-of-sentence (BOS), end-of-sentence (EOS)).
- The tensor goes through an embedding layer (this is somewhat similar to one-hot encoding and a matrix multiplication, see [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/29296/14675)). This gets us a vector for each character.
- The tensor goes through different 1D convolutions of configurable kernel sizes.
- The resulting activation maps are concatenated and passed as input to the highway networks

This architecture was proposed by [kim et al. (2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.06615), and is summarized well in one of the figures of the paper:

[image]

Comment: thank you, this is an excellent answer :) I tried to find the source code, but it seems I gave up too quickly.