# What is the ELMO approach to learn contextual embedding?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, tensorflow, pytorch

BERT, GPT, and ELMo used the contextual embedding. but, their approach of learning contextual embedding is different.

so, what is the ELMo approach to learn contextual embedding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELMo provides contextual word embeddings, but they are completely different to BERT's and GPT's in the following ways:

- ELMo processes its input at the character level by means of character n-gram convolutions. This allows ELMo to mitigate the out-of-vocabulary (OOV) problem, because it can represen words that is has not seen during training as long as they share the same script (Lating script, Cyrillic, etc) as the training data (see more details [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/97879/14675)). This architecture was proposed by [kim et al. (2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.06615), and is summarized well in one of the figures of the paper:

  [image]

  On the other hand, BERT and GPT use subwords as inputs.
- At its core, ELMo uses bidirectional LSTMs to perform its processing, while BERT uses a Transformer encoder and GPT a Transformer decoder.
- ELMo generates word-level contextual embeddings, while BERT and GPT generate subword embeddings.
- The training objective of ELMo is causal [bidirectional] language modeling (i.e. predicting the next word, in both directions of the text), while BERT uses a masked language modeling objective (i.e. predicting the masked token) and GPT a causal language modeling objective (i.e. predicting the next token).

Answer (score 1):

The main differences between BERT, GPT, and ELMo are the underlying model architecture and pre-training objective. BERT learns embeddings with Transformer (Vaswani et al., 2017) and its objective is Masked Language Modeling (MLM), GPT learns embeddings with Transformer and its objective is Causal Language Modeling. However, ELMo uses bi-directional LSTM (with two layers), and the objective of forward and backward LSTMs is also next-word prediction. In the simplest case, ELMo just selects the top layer activations as contextual embeddings, pools them, and uses it for a task-specific model.